# observable and promises in angular2 and ionic2 request fails

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

am trying to perform an observable action when a promise request has resolved but am unable to find how

After some research i found out that ionic2 storage get returns a promise and i would like to perform a http request which should return an observable

This is what i have tried but fails

```
constructor(storage:Storage){}

  getAll():Observable<any>{

     this.storage.get("token")
          .then(res=>{ //perform the get request after value of token is found
           if(res){

              return this._http.get(this.companiesurl+"?access-token="+res)//attach token 
                 .map(res=>res.json().data)

             }

          }

  }
```

The above function is called in a constructor

```
  this.chojeService.getAll().subscribe(respose => {
    this.users = response
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Promise`, you can wrap that in an `Observable` pretty easily:

```
const data: Observable<any> = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get("token"))
  .flatMap(res => res ? this._http.get("...") : Rx.Observable.of(undefined))
  .map(res => res.json().data)
```

Comment: by .flatMap(res)  is the res the value returned by the promise(this.storage.get..)

Comment: I'd advise to read the `flatMap` docs. I assume the http request returns an `Observable` (since you are mapping on it), so with regular `map` you'd end up with `Observable<Observable<Response>>`. `flatMap` as the name suggests, "flattens" it, and you'll have `Observable<Response>`. Also corrected the `undefined` part, `flatMap`'s mapping function should always return an `Observable`

Comment: am new to the concept of rxjs by this does it mean that ill return data (const data) in my function get all

Comment: so also does this mean that ill use this code in the getall() function and subscribe like previously:(this.chojeService....)

Comment: If you return `data` in your `getAll` function, you will be able to subscribe to the result of `getAll` and I expect it to work properly. Give it a try!